# Задний фон в Swing

Tags: java, swing

Почему картинка не отображается? И как можно её загрузить через JLabel?

```
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Main extends JFrame {

        private static final int width = 1024;
        private static final int heigth = 768;

        public Main() throws IOException{
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(new Dimension(width, heigth));
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            getContentPane().add(new BackgroundImage("bg.jpg"));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            new Main();
        }
    }

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BackgroundImage extends JPanel {

    private Image background;

    public BackgroundImage(String fileName){
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        graphics.drawImage(background,0,0, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите за правило:

```
    setVisible(true);
```

Вызывать всегда в конце и у вас все получится.
В итоге конструктор будет выглядеть так:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(width, heigth));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().add(new BackgroundImage("/test.jpg"));
    setVisible(true);
```